# Can an invited guest user signin using Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Can an invited guest user in Azure AD B2C signin using this Azure AD B2C and access a registered application?
What is the password in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invited guests are for admin purposes i.e. administer the B2C tenant.

Typically they would be e.g. in another Azure tenant and hence would use the password in that tenant.

Only local users i.e. users created via B2C SUSI policies can access applications.