# b2c - Guest account not a member

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I'm usign custom policies in Azure.
How to make any new account created as a visitor account and not a member please.

Can someone explain the differences between Guest and Member? What are consequences when creating a user in B2C?

Can't find it in the docs.

Comment: Does this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview) help?

Answer (score -1):

1. we have a choice to create  users only  with
   `UserType=Member` in Azure AD B2C.
2. **UserType=Guest is a implementation detail of Azure AD B2B** which is a
   feature of regular Azure AD and it is not supported in Azure AD B2C.
3. B2c Is designed basically for EXTERNALLY facing apps which have own
   app specific login credentials.

and so **There is no concept of a GUEST user for a B2C tenant.**

If one need  GUEST user type of access  for B2C users, then they would have to invite them separately to the main AzureAD tenant.

**References:**

1. [B2C Portal Login, B2C Guest Users - Cloud Identity Architect](https://cloudidentityarchitect.com/azure-ad/b2c-portal-login-b2c-guest-users/)
2. [Use map UserType with Azure AD Connect cloud sync | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-sync/how-to-map-usertype)
3. [can an invited guest user signin using azure ad b2c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719662/can-an-invited-guest-user-signin-using-azure-ad-b2c)

Comment: This answer is not correct. Azure AD B2C does provide the option to invite users as guests.